# Find the commonly related vertices of the traversed graph

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

Given this graph

```
g.addV("1").property(id,'a').as('a').
  addV("2").property(id,'b').as('b').
  addV("3").property(id,'c').as('c').
  addE('related').from('a').to('b').
  addE('related').from('a').to('c').
  addE('related').from('b').to('c')
```

[image: Graph]
[image: Graph]

If a selection of 1 and 2 is done.

```
g.V().hasLabel("1", "2").has("id", within("a","b"))
```

And I want to get the "commonly" related node, just doing:

```
g.V().hasLabel("1", "2").has("id", within("a","b")).out()
```

Won't cut it because it will give me 2 and 3 (when only 3 was intended)
Furthermore, if 2 and 3 is not related 3 should not be shown as a result because not all nodes of the "selection" relates to 3.

Is there any good way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Depending on the complexity of your actual graph, a simple solution is to `groupCount` the nodes that can be visited from the starting set and if the count is not the same as the number of nodes in the starting set then reject them. If that sounds useful in your case I can provide an example.

Comment: I went ahead and added an example that uses `groupCount`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that uses `groupCount`. Note that this assumes there are no parallel edges between any two adjacent vertices in the same direction.

```
gremlin> g.addV("1").property(id,'a').as('a').
......1>   addV("2").property(id,'b').as('b').
......2>   addV("3").property(id,'c').as('c').
......3>   addE('related').from('a').to('b').
......4>   addE('related').from('a').to('c').
......5>   addE('related').from('b').to('c')
==>e[2][b-related->c]

gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('1','2').out()
==>v[b]
==>v[c]
==>v[c]

gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('1','2').out().groupCount()
==>[v[b]:1,v[c]:2]

gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('1','2').out().groupCount().unfold().where(select(values).is(2))
==>v[c]=2

gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('1','2').out().groupCount().unfold().where(select(values).is(2)).select(keys)
==>v[c]
```

Comment: This is a great solution, I was playing around with trying to not keep track of the number and letting the query itself do it by saying :

`g.V("id1","id2").as('result').out().groupCount().unfold().where(select(values).is(select('result').count())).select(keys)`

But it doesnt seem to be the path forward, do you have any suggestions to resolve that?